# Firefox-addon-sdk: launching pageMod when pressing a button?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, toolbar, firefox-addon-sdk

I am making a Firefox add on using [toolbar button](https://github.com/voldsoftware/toolbarbutton-jplib) by Erik Vold and I would like to know how to launch and stop pageMod when an user press a button in the toolbar. Is that even possible ?
I tried injecting Javascript using this method and it didn't work quite well. Moreover I couldn't inject CSS.

Below is my current code, if that can help understanding the problem:

```
var tbb = require('toolbarbutton').ToolbarButton({
  id: 'button',
  label: 'us-button',
  image: self.data.url('img/on.png'),
  onCommand: function () {

    tabs.activeTab.attach ({

        contentScriptFile: [
            self.data.url('jquery/jquery.min.js'),
            self.data.url('jquery/jquery-ui.js'),
            self.data.url('recuperation.js'),
            self.data.url('dialog.js')
      ]
   });
  }
});
```

Comment: No there is no error. With `tabs.activeTab.attach`, we can't use `contentStyleFile` whereas with pageMod we can, so I'm looking for a way to call pageMod when I press a button in the toolbar.

Comment: There is no way to call `PageMod` for a specific tab. Its `include` property is mandatory and it works as a filter on pages as they load, not after they've loaded. See my answer below to inject CSS.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by

> It didn't work quite well?

Did it work at all? As long as `onCommand()` is being called, I don't see any problems with the code.

## As for the CSS

You're probably the one who filed the contentStyleFile bug (beat me to it), but for reference, it's been filed [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=882823) and they seem to be working on a fix.

In the meantime, I'm using javascript/jQuery.

### Main.js

```
var worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: [data.url('jquery.js'),
                        data.url('annotate.js')]
    contentScriptOptions: data.url('annotate.css')
});
```

### annotate.js

```
$('head').append("<link href='"+self.options+"' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />");
```

This could also be done in plain javascript, but I'm using jQuery elsewhere as well.